# Django Post.objects.all() does not show object attributes

Tags: python, django

Hey I am currently going through the Django girls tutorial http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/README.html

I am trying to display all of my Post objects in the python shell using

```
from blog.models import Post
Post.objects.all()
```

It should display

```
[<Post: Title>, <Post: Title2>]
```

but instead it displays

```
[<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>]
```

It just says "Post object" instead of the title.  What is the reason why? I have been following the tutorial exactly and can't understand why it displays it like that.  It's hard to organize all of the posts when it says "Post object" for all of them.

I am using Python version 3.4.1 and Djangon version 1.8.1.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you need to add a `__str__` instance method to your model to display the value you want to use as the representation of the instance.

Comment: `Django Girls` -- Interesting, never knew about that site/org. Neat. !

Comment: Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/330457) the answer that solved your problem instead of editing the title. Accepting will signal the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

In [Chapter 9](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/README.html#creating-a-blog-post-model) of the Django Girls Tutorial, there are instructions to create a [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#str) method for your `Post` model as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If you still can't get it to work, please update your question and include `Post` class. You might have made a mistake with the indentation (number of spaces).

Comment: Ahhh, this worked! I realized that I only had _str_ and not __str__, I misread the double underscore. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    # python 2.x
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    # python 3.x
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

through the Following Command

```
Post.objects.all()
```

You are Getting All the Posts From Your Database( in Your Case i.e 2)

that is why it is Showing

```
[<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>]
```

instead of

```
[<Post: Title>, <Post: Title2>]
```

To get The Following Output

You should Try

1. Method

   Post.objects.get(pk=1)

where pk is the id of the post

2. Method

   Post.objects.filter(id=1)

where id is the id of the post